# QAxObject: No such file or directory

Tags: qt

I have created a QT 5 Console Application for read an xls file, but when I include QAxBase and QAxObject header files it gives me following error:

```
error : QAxObject: No such file or directory
```

My code:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QAxBase>
#include <QAxObject>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

...

return a.exec();
}
```

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

You've probably already resolved this, but in any case. If you're using Linux then you can't use `QAxObject`.

If you're on Windows, you most likely just need to add `axcontainer` to your `project.pro` file:

```
QT  +=  core  gui  axcontainer
```